# Please explain the below unix code

Tags: unix, sed

```
 echo "1,a,20,000,aa,s" | sed 's/,\([^0]\)/|\1/g'  
 **output  
 1|a|20,000|aa|s**
```

Please explain the above command.

I am unable to understand this execution.

Comment: Unix or sed? Tag your question correctly.

Comment: What part of the command do you not understand?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The given command uses sed to substitute certain characters for other characters.

The basic form for this is

```
s/FIND/REPLACE/
```

where FIND and REPLACE are regular expressions.
The g at the end stands for global. It means that not only the first occurrence of a pattern matching FIND is replaced but all occurrences in the input string.

To the regular expressions used:

FIND ,`\([^0]\)` This pattern matches all two character strings who start with a `,` which is not followed by a `0`.

REPLACE `|\1` This is equal to a two character string who starts with a `|` which is followed by the second character in FIND. (The `\1` remembers the previously found match)

For a detailed overview of the sed commands I suggest you also read here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1

And to look up on how to read regular expressions: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

Of curse there are many more sites concerning this to be found if the above web-pages are not enlightening to you.